# How can i prevent liferay to add arguments to the url of an external file?

Tags: javascript, liferay

I load a js library by using `liferay-portlet.xml`. However, when the script is fetched, it is done using additional url arguments like `browserId` or `t`.

So, instead of having a "static" url `https://localhost:8443/portlet1/js/mypackage.js` the request looks like `https://localhost:8443/portlet1/js/mypackage.js?browserId=other&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6101&t=1391605782168`

Is there a way to prevent the addition of those arguments?

PS: liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<liferay-portlet-app>
  <portlet>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/mypackage.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
  </portlet>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

Comment: Are you sure of what are you asking about?

Comment: What makes you think that i'm not? Im not so deep into liferay, thats why im asking... (And its leaving away those arguments would be mainly for development purposes)

Comment: Liferay add this arguments for several puroposes, e.g. t-argument mean that the browser should reload the javascript-file by page-reload.

Comment: Okay. So the question could be reduced to: which settings control the above mentioned url arguments?

Comment: There parameters are necessary and i think there are not settings to change it. Tell us the reason you want remove it.